# Check if folder exists

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-content-engine

my structure is as follows

```
MyRootFolder

└──subfolder1
└──subfolder2
.
.
.
└──subfolder n
```

I have a requirement where-in I need to check if a sub-folder exists within a root folder and if not create it. I can't find a direct API to check for the sub-folder existence. Instead, I see an API like

```
folder.get_SubFolders();
```

which would give me a list of all the sub-folders and then iterate to check if sub-folder exists or not. The problem here is that I might end up having to iterate many folders which I don't want to do. Is there a different way to achieve this? I'm using Filenet 5.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, this is the closest option that I could find.

Search in FileNet for the subfolder using below query.

`SELECT FolderName FROM Folder WHERE FolderName='subfolder1' and Parent=OBJECT({parent-folder-guid})`

If the above search returns a result, the subfolder is present if not create one.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be - you try to create a folder you want, if already exists dont create it else create it. To achieve it you dont have to iterate through the existing folders. I had the same requirement for one of my project where I had to move the content from shared drive to FileNet P8 and assigning properties to them while maintaining the same folder paths. Following snippet might help someone:

```
public static Folder createFolderStructure() {
        Connection conn = Factory.Connection.getConnection(ConfigInfo.CE_URI);
        Domain dom = Factory.Domain.getInstance(conn, null);
        ObjectStore os = Factory.ObjectStore.getInstance(dom,
                ConfigInfo.OBJECT_STORE_NAME);
        Folder folder = null;

    // pass your desired folder string here, excluding the starting root "/"

    String folderpath = "APITest/some/folder/2014/12/2";

    System.out.println("\nGiven input folder path is :: " + folderpath + "\n");
    String[] myarray = folderpath.split("/");
    for (int x = 0; x < myarray.length; x++) {

        try {
            if (x == 0) {
                folder = Factory.Folder.createInstance(os, null);
                Folder rootFolder = Factory.Folder.getInstance(os, null, "/");
                folder.set_Parent(rootFolder);
                folder.set_FolderName(myarray[x]);
                System.out.println("Creating main (first) folder.. \t" + myarray[x]);
                folder.save(RefreshMode.NO_REFRESH);

            } else {
                String currentfolder = myarray[x];
                String parentfolder = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                    folder = Factory.Folder.createInstance(os, null);
                    parentfolder = parentfolder + "/" + myarray[i];
                    Folder nxtrootFolder = Factory.Folder.getInstance(os, null, parentfolder);
                    folder.set_Parent(nxtrootFolder);
                    folder.set_FolderName(currentfolder);
                }
                System.out
                        .println("Trying to create " + currentfolder + " in " + parentfolder);

                folder.save(RefreshMode.NO_REFRESH);
            }

        } catch (EngineRuntimeException ere) {
            ExceptionCode code = ere.getExceptionCode();
            if (code != ExceptionCode.E_NOT_UNIQUE) {
                throw ere;
            }
            System.out.println("Above folder already exists...skipping...");
        }

    }
    return folder;
}
```

This is copied from my own [blog](https://abcdjavaee.blogspot.com/2017/09/filenet-apis-quick-reference.html).